# Zend Framework :: How can I rollback from zend 2.6 to zend 2.3

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am using **zend2.6.0** but when I try to install csnUser ie libraries of zend framework by the following command **php composer.phar require coolcsn/csn-user:dev-maste**r it showing me error your requirement could not be resolved to and an installable set of packages.

Because csnUser need to be **zend 2.3 but I have 2.6 version so anyone tells me how to resolve that.**

Comment: or anyone just tell how can i install https://github.com/coolcsn/CsnUser in zend-framework 2.6.

Comment: coolcsn/CsnUser depends only on doctrine/doctrine-orm-module, so I don't see why it shouldn't work with zf 2.6. Could you update your question with the whole error message?

Answer (score 3):

in Composer change

```
 "zendframework/zendframework": "2.6.*",
```

to

```
 "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.1",
```

than compser update